# Is there a way to allow a user to delete a full word while reading a line in Go?

Tags: shell, go, terminal

I am trying to create a shell in Go. I currently have this code that reads the `os.Stdin` and prints it out.

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    buf := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)

    for {
        fmt.Print("> ")

        bytes, err := buf.ReadBytes('\n')
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }

        fmt.Println(strings.TrimSuffix(string(bytes), "\n"))
    }
}
```

However, while you are typing out your commands, I found that you can not use `Command` + `Backspace` to delete a full word like you can usually do in a shell. I found this issue to be pretty annoying and after looking at other similar questions on StackOverflow I saw that some people mentioned that the terminal needs to be in raw mode.

I have tried using `termbox-go`, but I was not able to get it working. If anyone could point me in the right direction it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi! What terminal emulator are you using to run your shell? Where is it picking up standard input? I'm thinking maybe your terminal emulator/previous shell could be getting in the middle. For example, if I run it like any other program my regular shell won't send any line until I hit \n... so the "golang shell" only sees the final line.

I guess you'll have to 1) make sure you are getting the raw input from the terminal/terminal emulator you are using and 2) have your shell read byte by byte instead of full lines, to intercept the special characters (such as C-w)

Comment: @JuanManuelFresia Thank you for commenting! I am using the standard Terminal (Version 2.11 (440)) on MacOS BigSur. I believe I do need to read STDIN byte by byte, but I have not figured out a way to do so yet.

Comment: Check under the Terminal settings (Profiles->Keyboard) and you'll find some key combinations that get translated by the terminal emulator... maybe you can make it send a specific character that you can later parse. But I'd search for some terminal emulator that sends you the raw keyboard input.

Comment: @JuanManuelFresia Thanks for the suggestion, but I do not think the Terminal Emulator is the problem. For example, the PostgreSQL shell can works perfectly fine if I try to delete a full word with command backspace. I will take a look at the source code of PostgreSQL's shell when I have time and see if I can figure out what to do in Go.